# No module named 'keras.saving.hdf5_format'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After `pip3 install`ing `tensorflow` and the `transformers` library, I'm receiving the titular error when I try loading [this](https://huggingface.co/bhadresh-savani/distilbert-base-uncased-emotion)

```py
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("text-classification",model='bhadresh-savani/distilbert-base-uncased-emotion')
```

The error traceback looks like:

```bash
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.distilbert.modeling_tf_distilbert because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'keras.saving.hdf5_format'
```

I have ensured keras got installed with transformers, so I'm not sure why it isn't working

Comment: As a workaround, I ended up using pyTorch

Comment: Hi, possibly Keras and Tensorflow are mismatched for Windows look at 

# C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\__pycache__
( keras==2.8.0, tensorflow==2.8.0, tensorflow-estimator==2.8.0, tensorflow-hub==0.7.0 )

Comment: I'm using Linux, and used the latest version so both (fresh install)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of TensorFlow and Keras then you have to try this code and you have got this error as shown below

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.distilbert.modeling_tf_distilbert because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'keras.saving.hdf5_format'
```

Now, expand this error traces as I have shown below

[image: Click on the 14 frames]

Now click on the 14 frames and select as shown below
[image: Click on modeling_tf_utils.py]
Now comment this line as shown in the picture below
[image: Comment this from keras.saving.hdf5_format import save_attributes_to_hdf5_group]

Now, try this and your error will gone.

The problem is that this is in the older version of keras and you are using the latest version of keras. So, you can skip all these steps and go back to the older version and it will work eventually.

Comment: Same as me Keras and Tensorflow==2.8.0 that is because sklearn the same problems.

Comment: Tensorflow 2.11 broke for me with the issue reported above.  Rolling back to 2.10 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I confirm that:

```
pip install -U tensorflow==2.10
```

fixes it and now e.g. this runs:

```
pytest -s
============================================================================ test session starts ============================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/codespace/Downloads
plugins: anyio-3.6.2, typeguard-2.13.3
collected 0 items
```